# Remove child node from sitemap in master page

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, menuitem

I am using asp:Menu to show menubar. The menu control uses sitemap as datasource. Now I want to delete some child nodes from sitemap node based on permission. I tried to manipulate Mennuitems but unable to delete that child node.

This is code to my menu control

```
<td class="TRMenu" valign="middle" align="left">
    <asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" Orientation="Horizontal"
                DataSourceID="newSiteMap">
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="newSiteMap" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" StartingNodeUrl="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Default.aspx" />
</td>
```

This is the code to my sitemap

```
<siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Default.aspx" title="SPONSOR"  description="SPONSOR">
    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Home.aspx" title="HOME"  description="HOME" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Default.aspx?0" title="Dash Board"  description="Dash Board" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/SiteViewAll.aspx" title="Site Info."  description="Site Information" id="Site">
        <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Site.aspx" title="Add/Update Site Info."  description="Add/Update Site Information" id="Add"/>
        <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/SiteViewAll.aspx?0" title="View Site Info."  description="View Site Information" />
    </siteMapNode>


    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/UserViewAll.aspx" title="User Info."  description="User Info" >
        <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/User.aspx?New" title="Add/Update User Info."  description="Add/Update User Information" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/UserViewHirerchical.aspx" title="View Hirerchical User"  description="View Hirerchical User Information" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/UserViewAll.aspx?0" title="View User Info."  description="View User Information" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <!--<siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/CRFProtocol.aspx" title="CRF Protocol"  description="CRF Protocol" />-->
    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/eCRFDownload.aspx" title="CRF Download Forms"  description="CRF Download Forms" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/LogSheet.aspx" title="Log Sheet"  description="Log Sheet" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx?logout=SPONSOR" title="Logout"  description="Logout" />
</siteMapNode>
```

I want to remove below node based on the permission

```
<siteMapNode url="~/_PL/SPONSOR/Site.aspx" title="Add/Update Site Info."  description="Add/Update Site Information" id="Add"/>
```

I have tried following method.

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (MenuItem Item in menu.Items)
    {
        if (Item.Text.Contains("Site"))
        {
            string str = Item.ChildItems[0].Text;
            Item.ChildItems.RemoveAt(0);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried this in page load and prerender methods also but still the node is there when the page is loaded.

How can I remove it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think right way to implement it is in the DataBound-Event of the menu-control:

```
<asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Orientation="Horizontal" OnDataBound="Menu_DataBound" DataSourceID="newSiteMap">
```

```
protected void Menu_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (MenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        if (Item.Text.Contains("Site"))
        {
        string str = Item.ChildItems[0].Text;
        Item.ChildItems.RemoveAt(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Page.Unload-Event finds Items but seems not to be able to influence state of controls any more (probably because it is meant for other things).